# How to find out why GNOME/Openbox session doesn't work on 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 22.04, openbox

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.02, and I would like to use Openbox with GNOME.

However, if I choose the GNOME/Openbox option when logging in, I get the sad monitor image and the message "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." with a Log Out button.

After the default install I installed the *openbox* and *openbox-gnome-session* packages. Maybe this isn't enough?

I've looked in syslog and in `/home/$user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.*log`, but nothing stood out, although there were lots of warnings that may be relevant, such as shown below.

No files are present in `/var/crash`.

Note that all the other options that can be selected while logging in (Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Xorg, GNOME, GNOME on Xorg, and even Openbox, do work).

I've also tried logging in with a newly created test user and the result is the same.

Thanks for any pointers on where to look for a solution! I've read that it might be useful to start the session from a text console instead of a graphical login screen, but I don't (yet) know how to do that.

```
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Starting GNOME Session Manager (session: openbox-gnome)...
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'gnome-panel'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'gnome-panel'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'nautilus-classic'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'nautilus-classic'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'gnome-flashback-services'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'gnome-flashback-services'
```

```
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Starting IBus Daemon for GNOME...
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Starting GNOME XSettings service...
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: Entering running state
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Finished Signal initialization done to GNOME Session Manager.
May  3 20:16:15 spork sh[54284]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Failed to start IBus Daemon for GNOME.
May  3 20:16:15 spork gsd-xsettings[54282]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
```

```
May  3 20:16:15 spork systemd[53894]: Started GPaste daemon.
May  3 20:16:15 spork gpaste-daemon[54297]: Couldn't grab keybindings with gnome-shell: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files
May  3 20:16:15 spork dbus-daemon[53917]: [session uid=1001 pid=53917] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session[54263]: gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Could not retrieve current screensaver active state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
May  3 20:16:15 spork gnome-session-binary[54263]: WARNING: Could not retrieve current screensaver active state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

And most notably:

```
May  3 20:16:25 spork gnome-shell[53265]: Connection to xwayland lost
May  3 20:16:25 spork gdm-launch-environment]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
May  3 20:16:25 spork gdm3: Gdm: Child process -53200 was already dead.
```

Comment: How old is this software. I was just reading the install docs and it talks about Ubuntu 8.04

Comment: Yes, it's quite old. This is more of a question about how to debug this, then about the actual software itself (which works, given that I can use it as window manager without gnome..)

Comment: It appears to be simply too old. Nothing to debug.

Comment: Do you have a source for that statement? I mean, even if it would be tool old, I'd expect a message somewhere or other saying something isn't supported. Also, it's still packaged, and it shows up in the login menu, so I assume it has been working with GNOME in the past. I just don't know if this is a problem on my machine, or a problem with the software or packaging..

Comment: Also, according to Arch documentation this is possible, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks#Custom_GNOME_sessions